# Angular 4 error with angular core change detection differs after upgrade from 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-upgrade

I have a ng2 website I upgraded to ng4. On building, I get an error

```
ERROR in /home/docker/urlmgr-client/node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/iterable_differs.d.ts
```

(15,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.

It is the only error and I never got this error in ng2.

I'm not sure where to begin debugging this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a dependency error to me. With [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) you can easily check and update your dependencies after upgrading from Angular 2.

Comment: How is it a dependency error if it is in angular core? The offending line in the file is" export declare type NgIterable<T> = Array<T> | Iterable<T>;"

Comment: I updated via npm-check-updates but still have the error.

Comment: I added the following to the top of the file and it compiles now- "declare type Iterable<T> = any;"

Comment: Glad you figured it out =)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it is due to having a file left over from Angular 2. You will need to delete the node_modules folder and reinstall Angular.

Adding "export declare type NgIterable = Array | Iterable" is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will give it a try.

Comment: Thank you so much; this saved me. I was in a panic as I'm not that familiar with all the crap angular loads in that folder. Whew, and upvoted. Should definitely be marked as the answer.